# How to acess bookmarks in touch browser

Tags: ubuntu-touch, smartphone

On BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition in internet browser: I assume hitting star is a way to save bookmarks. I can't find a way to access already saved bookmarks. Top right menu only shows:

- share
- history
- open tabs
- new tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking on **New tab** you will see a **Search/ Address bar**, your **Bookmarks** and **Top sites** (which seem to be your most visited websites).